# How to install SSL on CloudFront correctly?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

Hi I've just purchased an SSL for my domain. After contacting with my SSL provision I have 5 files from my provider.

```
my_domain.crt
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt
USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.rt
my_domain.private_key
```

My provider said that I have to install all of them.

I used AWS CLI to install with this command.

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name my_domain \
--certificate-body file://my_domain.crt \
--private-key file://my_domain.private_key \
--certificate-chain file:://AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt \
--path /cloudfront/
```

I tried with all the .crt files but only `TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5.crt` went through.

The others I got this error.

> A client error (MalformedCertificate) occured when calling the
>   UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to validate certificate
>   chain must start with the immediate signing certificate, followed by
>   any intermediaries in order.

And after using `https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html` to check my SSL I got this.

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate. Learn more about this error. The fastest way to fix this
>   problem is to contact your SSL provider.

```
Common name: my_domain
SANs: my_domain
Organization: My Org
Location:  US
Valid from : Date
Serial Number: 
Signature Algorithm: 
Issuer: Trusted Secure Certificate Authority 5  

Common name: Trusted Secure Certificate Authority 5
Organization: Corporation Service Company
Location: Wilmington, DE, US
Valid from September 9, 2014 to September 9, 2024
Serial Number: 
Signature Algorithm: 
Issuer: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate chain file is a "chain" of trust.  It is a combination of the contents of all (usually) of the provided `*Trust*.crt` files, and they need to be combined in a specific order, including the begin/end lines found in each file.

All of the the `.crt` files have a Subject (the entity the certificate is certifying as being valid) and an Issuer (the entity signing the certificate).

You have to build and present this "chain" of trust so that each certificate's Subject reflects the Issuer of the *prior* certificate.

Use `openssl x509 -text -noout -in <filename>` on your domain's cert and then on each of the `*Trust*.crt` cert files to find their "Issuer" and "Subject" values.

Starting with the Issuer value seen in your domain's cert, find the .crt file with your domain's cert's Issuer value shown... as the Subject.  That file will be first in the chain.

Then take note of that file's Issuer and find the next file, which will have a Subject to match the prior file's Issuer... and so on, until you figure out the order in which to assemble them.  The last cert in the chain will most likely have the same value for both Issuer and Subject, since it's the end of the chain.

Combine the contents of the three `*Trust*.crt` files, in the order determined by the steps above, into a new file, and use that new file you created as the "certificate chain" file. Remember that your domain's .crt file doesn't go in the chain file, since you're sending it separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say 'combined'. How do you mean? How do I combine the chain. I know the order of the chain already. Or do I need to run the command three times?

Comment: Or do I physically combine the content of the file?

Comment: Just concatenate them together into a new file, e.g. `cat first.crt second.crt third.crt > chain.crt` then use the new `chain.crt` file as the certificate chain, running the aws command only once.

Comment: I concat them in the correct order but Amazon still saying that the certificate is malformed.

Comment: Is there anyway I can validate the new `pem` file?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here. I specify `--certificate-body` as my  `domain.crt` When you mentioned it will be sent separately. How do you mean?

Comment: No, you are correct. By "sent separately" I meant it's not to be combined into the chain file, because it is sent as a separate file `--certificate-body file://domain.crt` like you are doing.

Comment: Did you verify the correct order as I described it?

Comment: Yes the order is correct as it's specified here http://www.csctrustedsecure.com/support/index.shtml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78479/discussion-between-toy-and-michael-sqlbot).

Comment: There was a typo on my command now everything works fine. Thanks a lot!